# Add to cart button showing in configurable products but not in simple products in magento

Tags: php, magento

http://geecosme.nextmp.net/weaves/human-multiway-weave-135/human-multiway-weave.html

Its a configurable product.
here you could see that add to cart ('add to bag') button is there.

http://geecosme.nextmp.net/weaves/human-multiway-weave-135/human-multiway-weave-18-inches-darkest-black-120-grams.html

This is a simple product
In this simple product add to cart button is not showing. I have checked everything from quantity to availability and even reindexed data after setting manage to No. still nothing.

Its ajax based add to cart button.

Answer (score 0):

Simple products that have a parent configurable product shouldn't be visible individually.

Magento will check if it has a stock on the simple product and will show it as an option in configurable.